# JQuery Caroufredsel not working, displays all images

Tags: jquery, gallery, carousel, caroufredsel

I just installed caroufredsel and its not working. What I am expecting to happen is, 1 images appears, I click next or previous the next or previous image would appear. The code below just has all my images display in a list. I do understand what I am doing wrong as my code seems correct?

Here is my JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.caroufredsel-gallery').carouFredSel({
                    width: 601,
                    height: 'auto',
                    prev: '#prev3',
                    next: '#next3',
                    auto: false
                });

        </script>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div>
            <ul class="caroufredsel-gallery">

                    <li><img src="images/gallery/1.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/2.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/3.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/4.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/5.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/6.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/7.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/gallery/8.jpg" width="601" /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a id="prev3" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
                <a id="next3" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
            </div><!--caroufredsel-gallery-->
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things to try:

- Put this snippet in your caroufredsel call `(items :1, scroll : 1)`
- Put this in your css `(.caroufredsel-gallery li { float: left; })`

Hopefully, that helps.  Also, check the console in whatever browser you're using to make sure that the plugin is actually being called.  It could be that or even that jQuery isn't being found.  Pressing F12 should get you to the Console. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script within a function. That should work. Final script should look like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('.caroufredsel-gallery').carouFredSel({
                width: 601,
                height: 'auto',
                prev: '#prev3',
                next: '#next3',
                auto: false
            });
       });
    </script>
```